# Storing a date in a 16 bits

Tags: c++, date

I want to store dates in a 16 bit in a way like:

```
High Bytes: Y Y Y Y Y Y Y M
Low Bytes:  M M M D D D D D
```

With the values being in the following ranges

```
Year:  0 - 99
Month: 1 - 12
Day:   1 to 31
```

I realize that it would be something like this

```
byte a = (year << 10) + (month << 6) + day.
```

Comment: You should try something, then ask a specific question if and when you run into problems.

Comment: @juanchopanza I've edited the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Encode:

```
((year - year0) << 9) + (month << 5) + day
```

Decode:

```
year  = (date >> 9) + year0;
month = (date >> 5) & 15;
day   = date & 31;
```

Comment: @yzt: Thanks for the year0 correction, but I like to keep my answers down to the bare essentials.

Comment: Absolutely. It's your answer, with your name on it. I just thought it would help the OP more, seeing his/her apparent level of programming skills.

Answer (score 1):

```
(year<<9) | (month<<5) | day;
```